# Clearing page style, but adding on page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}    
    \newpage

    \section{Preface} %want section number to be 0
    \thispagestyle{empty}    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage

    \section{Start From Here}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{And So On...}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \end{document}
```

Currently I have page numbering and title in the header and for both the header and footer I have a line (I'm not sure what it's called). For the preface, I want all of that gone, which is why I used `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but I *do* want a roman page numbering in the bottom center.

> How can I get the page numbering on the preface to show a roman numeral? (As of now it only shows in ToC).

Comment: How do you get page number and title in the header? A viable solution needs to know this information.

Comment: Now that the problem has been solved, perhaps you should add again the relevant information about your headers/footers; by the way, did my answer solved the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a new page style using `\fancypagestyle{<name>}{<commands>}` to get rid of other headers/footers and leave the page number, and then use `\thispagestyle{<name>}` at the desired locations:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{myplain}
{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CE]{\hdrtitle}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}%don't move this

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\makeatletter
\let\hdrtitle\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\section{Preface}
\thispagestyle{myplain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage

\section{Start From Here}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{And So On...}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The solution above will work if the preface is one page long; if the preface spans more than one page, you could define two styles: for example, `myplain` (with only the page number (I assumed it should be centered in the footer, but you can easily change this)), and `myfancy` (with your header/footer and rules);  then you can use `\pagestyle{<style>}` at appropriate locations to switch styles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{myplain}
{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[CE]{\hdrtitle}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%don't move this
}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\makeatletter
\let\hdrtitle\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\pagestyle{myplain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section{Preface}
\lipsum[1-10]
\newpage

\pagestyle{myfancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Start From Here}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{And So On...}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you could be interested in using the `book` document class and its `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` commands? (using \chapter as the high level sectional unit, of course).

Comment: but that doesn't clear header and footer in the preface?

Comment: @AlanH please see my updated answer.