# Wide figure on double page

Tags: floats, double-sided

I've been searching for a way to display a large figure on a double page. So far I haven't find anything to do so.

Is this possible without cutting the figure in two?

Is it possible to change the paper format in LaTeX, in order to double the width only for one figure (i.e. not for all the text)? (**Edit**: in fact no, I don't want that)

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**:

I have improvised a way to insert a special page (with double width) with this code:

```
\newcommand\imagedoublepage[1]{
\newpage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=27cm \pdfpageheight=21cm

\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width = 25cm]{fig/#1}
\setcounter{page}{\thepage+1}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry

\eject  \pdfpagewidth=13.5cm \pdfpageheight=21cm

}
```

However, this is not great for two reasons: 1. it seems to me that this is not a very clean solution 2. it is very hard to print !!

In fact, I now observe that I really need to break my figure on two pages. It is much more convenient for the impression.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ... `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` is the environment to fix the image for two column format. And regarding paper format, please provide your `MWE`...

Comment: To split an image, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347152/clip-an-a3-tikz-overlay-to-two-a4-pages.  To change paper size, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239786/landscape-a3-page-in-portrait-a4-document-adds-a-blank-page-or-reorients-previ or search for \eject.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I'm not asking for a two column format, but for a double page situation.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, can you show show some screenshot for better understanding...

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've updated my question. Changing the paper size is not very convenient for the impression ... Your link to split an image is about tikz, but I have not really understand how to make it work with an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tikz is used to clip and position the image (stored in a savebox) on the page.  Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\master}

\savebox{\master}{\includegraphics[width=2\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \clip (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);% not needed
  \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (current page.east) {\usebox{\master}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \clip (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);% not needed
  \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (current page.west) {\usebox{\master}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perf! I use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107473/clearing-page-style-but-adding-on-page-number to make sure that the first page is on the left :)