# Why the header does not show?

Tags: header-footer, chapters

Why the Preface chatper does not show the header `Preface`?

By the way, I am writing the `Preface` chapter ( I wrote it as `\chapter*{Preface}`) before the `tableofcontents`. because if I write it after the tableofcontents it will mess up the page numbering. Am I doing the right thing?

You are welcome to edit the post.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: here is my commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thesection. \ }{\thesection\ }{}{}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\textwidth= 6.4in

\textheight= 8.0in

\topmargin = -18pt

\evensidemargin=0pt

\oddsidemargin=0pt

\headsep=20pt

\parskip=10pt

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}

\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}

\hypersetup{linkcolor={c1},citecolor={c2},urlcolor={c3}}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{...}
\author{...}
\maketitle
    
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Preface}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Notations}

\newpage

\setcounter{page}{0}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{...}

\chapter{...}

.

.

.\bibliography{...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the only purpose of the empty page style is to remove the page head and foot so why have you specified this if you do not want the page header to go? It is impossible to debug just lines of code out of context please include a small document that shows the issue.

Comment: @David Carlisle I just learned it from a youtube tutorial and i dont know how it works i just copied it down. I am new to latex. let me delete it and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle first question is solved. What about the other question regarding `preface`?

Comment: @AliShadhar  your question needs follow the format as shown here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107473/clearing-page-style-but-adding-on-page-number?rq=1

Comment: @David Carlisle I agree with you. I am still learning even about how to ask questions. I will provide details.

Comment: @David Carlisle I edited my post. I hope its clear now.

Comment: @js bibra Thank you

Comment: @Mico can you help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, why you used the package `fancyhdr`, so I removed it. In standard `book` class file `\pagestyle{headings}` is the default one, so no need to call it sesparately.

`\frontmatter` tag will handle the `\pagenumbering{roman}` by auto, and `\mainmatter` will handle all the tags `\setcounter{page}{0}\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}`

`\markboth` tag will solve the header issue in `Preface`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thesection. \ }{\thesection\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\textwidth= 6.4in
\textheight= 8.0in
\topmargin = -18pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt

\headsep=20pt
\parskip=10pt

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}

\hypersetup{linkcolor={c1},citecolor={c2},urlcolor={c3}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{Book Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
    
\chapter*{Preface}
\markboth{Preface}{Preface}
\lipsum[1-10]

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Notations}

\lipsum[1-3]

\newpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[1-10]

\backmatter
%\bibliography{...}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've just retained all the tags `\patchcmd{` as I'm not sure what purpose you used these...

Comment: Thank you Mady. +1